# Moment.js Range - Get specific weekdays within a moment range

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, momentjs

I have a range of dates:

```
var from = moment("01/01/2018", "DD/MM/YYYY")
var to = moment("31/01/2018", "DD/MM/YYYY")
var range = moment.range(from, to)
```

What I need is to get the ranges from the above range for specific days!
For example: If I need ONLY the ranges from Monday to Thursday, the result would be:

> 01/01/2018 - 04/01/2018
>  08/01/2018 - 11/01/2018
>  15/01/2018 -
>   18/01/2018
>  22/01/2018 - 25/01/2018
>  29/01/2018 - 31/01/2018

Please not that a user might need to get the ranges of days for days like: Monday, Wednesday, Thursday, Sunday - which complicates things...

Is there a clever way to do this in moment range, rather than reading each day from a range array and have result by day?

**One solution to the problem is by separating the range to an array of days:**

For example: Let weekdays be: 0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, 2 = Tuesday... etc

```
var weekdays = [0,1,2,3]
var range = moment.range(from, to)
rangeDate = Array.from(range.by('day',{ step: 1 }))
dailyRange = rangeDate.filter( date => weekdays.includes(date.day()) )
```

The result is the filtered days that you need in an array! 
The problem with this is that you get a daily result, not ranges result where range can be applied ( when 2 or more days are in sequence )!

Comment: that functionality is not included in the range plugin for moment. but you can implement this by your own, checking that the range includes at least 1 of that specific day, and adding 7 days until you reach your end date.

you can probably do this in better time if you check if a date falls within a range, which *is supported* by the range plugin for moment.js

Do you have any code to share that tries to implement that or try to use your implementation? stackoverflow is there to help with code problems, but you didn't add the actual code problem you're facing.